# Archiving fragmented data into a single file to optimize download from azure blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have image files totalling ~50GB stored in Azure blob. Avg file size is ~4KB. I'm using `azcopy` to download these to my Ubuntu-based local environment.

Performance wise, downloading these files one by one - which is what `azcopy` is doing right now - is probably as slow as I can do this. Is there a better strategy?

Ideally, I want to be able to archive the files into a single file, and then transfer that. Is there any way to do that with `azcopy` on Ubuntu?

Comment: Why not just archive it by yourself locally and then use AzCopy to upload the created archive?

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft: well the question is more about `downloading` from Azure blob. By the time I'll put it in an archive on my local system, I would have already faced the full brunt. There's no way to log into a `blob` terminal of sorts and do the archiving?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do so. Not about AzCopy implementation, it's due to Azure Storage Service doesn't provide such API.